# Stumped on trying to align header and navigation bar

Tags: html, css, header, alignment, nav

I can't seem to find the right way to align my header and my nav bar on this site. I know I'm missing something here.

Currently, the nav bar sits lower than the header:
https://angelicanicolle.github.io/angelicanicolle/

Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/angelicanicolle/angelicanicolle

```
      <!----------------------------------
              HEADER/LOGO
  ----------------------------------->
  <div class="header">
      <div class="head-logo">
        <a href="index.html" id="head">
          <img src='img/logo.png' id="logo">
          <div class="head-text">
            <h1>Hello, my name is Angelica Nicolle.</h1>
            <h2>Designer / Photographer / Artist of sorts</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
   </div>


  <!----------------------------------
              NAV BAR
  ----------------------------------->
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://angelicanicolle.com">Work</a></li>

          <li><a href="http://angelicanicolle.com">Journal</a></li>

          <li><a href="http://angelicanicolle.com">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

.header { float: left; margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 25px 0 0 0; position:relative; width: 100%;}

.head-logo {
margin: 0 0 0 .5%;
float: left;
padding: 20px;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;}

nav {text-align: right; margin: 0 0 10px 0; background: #fff;}
```

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your `<header>...</header>` tags to `<div>...</div>` and give a padding top of around 45px to your `<nav></nav>`. Something like this:

```
<nav style="padding-top:45px;">
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't help any

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS: nav{ padding-top:60px }